# Clearing a Printer Queue correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

**Scenario** -
After creating an application which is able to add and remove printers from users machines' I'm encountering a key bug:

1) The printer will not be removed if print jobs exist within the print queue (System32\spool\PRINTERS), these are SPL and SHD files

2) If there's a file with the size 23,000kb I need a way to stop the process until the command is completed

**My Current Method Flow**

```
                    Dim p As Process = New Process()
                    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"

                    For i = 0 To 2
                        Select Case i
                            Case 0
                                'Stop spooler and dependencies
                                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net stop spooler /yes"
                                p.Start()

                            Case 1
                                'Delete all queues within folder
                                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c del C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.* /F /Q"
                                p.Start()

                                'Delete printer
                                printer.Delete()

                            Case 2
                                'Restart the spooler service
                                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net start spooler"
                                p.Start()

                        End Select
                    Next
```

**With Threading**   :

```
    Dim p As Process = New Process()
                    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"

                    For i = 0 To 2
                        Select Case i
                            Case 0
                                'Stop spooler and dependencies
                                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net stop spooler /yes"
                                p.Start()
                                'Allow time for the application to purge larger file sizes
                                Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500)
                            Case 1
                                'Delete all queues within folder
                                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c del C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.* /F /Q"
                                p.Start()

                                'Delete printer
                                printer.Delete()

                            Case 2
                                'Restart the spooler service
                                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net start spooler"
                                p.Start()

                                Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500)
                        End Select
                    Next
```

Both these methods will not work correctly, the application doesn't allow enough time for the spooler service to stop. This means the files will not be deleted causing errors when deleting the printer.

**What I hope to gain from this thread**:

What I need is some guidance on how to operate this procedure efficiently. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stop the service from within your code:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.ServiceProcess
'........

Sub StopService(ByVal serviceName As String)

    Using sc = New ServiceController(serviceName)
        Dim ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
        Try
            sc.Stop()
            sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, ts)
            log.AppendFormatLine("Stopped {0} service.", serviceName)
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            log.AppendFormatLine("** Could not stop {0} service because {1}.", serviceName, ex.Message)
        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            log.AppendFormatLine("** Timeout after waiting {0} seconds for {1} service to stop.", ts.Seconds.ToString)
        End Try
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, however, it's revealed a new bug within my application *sigh*. Thanks for the help Andrew, kudos